# CV Views not making sense

Tags: support, jobs

I was looking through my stats on CV and it show 26 views from the private CV path:
[26 views from private cv path http://community.mediabrowser.tv/uploads/site_1/19/cv2.PNG](http://community.mediabrowser.tv/uploads/site_1/19/cv2.PNG)

However my stats are:

[alt text http://community.mediabrowser.tv/uploads/site_1/18/cv1.PNG](http://community.mediabrowser.tv/uploads/site_1/18/cv1.PNG)

Somewhere something appears not to be adding up. The stats say only one employer viewed my CV. Does this mean the same employer visited my CV multiple times over the last month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't employer views, those are yours from when you view the "employer view" tab. If an employer views your CV, you'll see `/employer/cv/<your-careers-user-number>` in your log. That is, if Google Analytics is capable of tracking them - how are you linking to GA from your CV?

Comment: Maybe a 1px by 1px image? Who knows?

Comment: @George: that's how I track mine, but I thought GA needed JS on the page to track it?

Comment: Im tracking this from the other end, the stats are coming from http://community.mediabrowser.tv there is nothing tracking things on my cv page, so in reality I would expect that less that 100% of the visitors on my cv would click on http://community.mediabrowser.tv also I am using the standard js provided by google to do the tracking.

Comment: Perhaps Jeff and co. are not tracking stuff they (the admins do) or perhaps there is a bug. I dunno.

Comment: @waffles If you're just tracking hits to your site from careers, then it seems that no one except you has navigated to your site from your CV, as only you have access to `/cv/view/private`.

Comment: I swear I did not click on it in the last few days, it must be Jeff and co.

Comment: The only other possibility is that someone else has a link to your site in their CV, which is probably unlikely. Other than that I have no idea.

Comment: For the record, I misunderstood how http referer works, hence the confusion. it does not mean you clicked on a link, it just points to the previous site see the rfc which is slightly ambiguous on how browsers should implement it.

Answer (score 2):

The only way **private CV employer views** would show up in your logs, is if:

1. you've embedded an image in your private CV, from a website you control
2. an employer clicks through to your private CV from search results

Employer search results themselves are screened heavily and disallowed from including any sort of images or other tracking mechanisms. So you will not see any requests to your server from employer search results pages.

Note that public CV views are completely unrelated to any of this.

Comment: My logs are showing that 3 people clicked through from my SO CV to my site from a path on careers that is /cv/view/private yesterday. Its not me ... and its not employers ... so I wonder where this came from .. internal testing perhaps?

Comment: maybe you could email us the IPs? We can't think of any way this is possible. From our perspective, we log to the database on code action, so there's no way (we can think of) that it would be incorrect.

Comment: plus, as Kyle pointed out, the employers would view through `/employer/cv/<your-careers-user-number>` -- `/cv/view/private` is from the self-preview

Comment: I suspect that this is due to http_referer shananigens, I did visit the CV site a few times yesterday and the next site I visited was the site in question. I guess the browser is incorrectly assuming that the CV site is the reason why I got to the site thus mucking up my stats. will test it ...